# How use GetOpt and LongOpt with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, getopt

In my project, based on Gradle, i need parse command line and get option "`-foo=...`".
I try to use Getopt, but i can't understand some things:

I need to use LongOpt to read "-foo" from command line ?
How can i pass arguments to command line, with "gradle run" command ?

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradle run` is intended to launch an application without any arguments.  You can hack around that if your arguments are pretty simple.

e.g.:

```
apply plugin: 'application'

run {
   if (project.hasProperty("runArgs")) {
      args project.runArgs.split()
   }
}
```

Run it with `gradle run -PrunArgs="arg1 arg2 arg3"`

This is pretty cumbersome to type and if your arguments need to be escaped or have spaces, it's going to be harder to handle.  At that point, I'd recommend just running `gradle installApp` and then the appropriate start script (`build/install/<app>/bin/<app> arg1 arg2 arg3`).

You can of course do something more elaborate: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_can_i_provide_command_line_args_to_application_started_with_gradle_run

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
gradle -q -Pfoo=bar printProps
```

in build.gradle

```
task printProps << {
    println foo
}
```

output

```
bar
```

An example [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)